# Python - Split string with " "

Tags: python, string, parsing

I know this is a basic question, but I'm having difficult with parsing some text.

So how the system will work, let's take the following example:

```
> set title "Hello world"
```

I should therefore get:

```
["set title", "Hello world"]
```

The problem is therefore, I need to split the string so when I enter, for example:

```
> plot("data.txt");
```

Should give me:

```
["plot", "data.txt"]
```

I have tried the following:

```
While True:
       command = raw_input(">");
       parse = command.split("' '");

       if(parse[0] == "set title"):
               title = parse[1];
```

But this does not work and will not even recognise that I am entering "set title"

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. if you split on the space `plot("data.txt")` you'd get: `['plot("data.txt")]` since it doesn't contain any space. Why would the parenthesis disappear in the result? I believe you don't want to "split", you want to *parse* the command line into tokens. That's generally done with regexes.

Comment: @Bakuriu Sorry.. It would be `plot 'data.txt'` not the one in the post, my bad

Comment: You should first start by designing a sane syntax/notation. How would the parser know not to split "set title" but to not split the others?

Comment: You can use [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split), it will preserve spaces inside strings. But that's not enough. There is no way to understand that you shouldn't split on the space of `set title` with just a simple operation such as a "split" on a separator. You need a bit of more complex logic to check the tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `split`. You need `re`:

```
import re
def parse(command):
    regex = r'(.*) "(.*)"'
    items = list(re.match(regex, command).groups())
    return items

if __name__ == '__main__':
    command = 'set title "Hello world"'
    print parse(command)
```

returns

```
['set title', 'Hello world']
```

Answer (score 0):

To split the string by blanks you need to use

```
parse = command.split(' ')
```

For the input "set title" you will get a parse array looking like this

```
['set', 'title']
```

where `parse[0] == 'set'` and `parse[1] == 'title'`

If you want to test whether your string starts with "set title", either check the `command` string itself or check the first two indexes of `parse`.

Answer (score 0):

```
split("' '")
```

Will split on the literal sequence of three characters single quote, space, single quote, which don't appear in your `command` strings.

I think you will need to approach this more like:

```
command, content = command.split(" ", 1)
if command == "plot":
    plot(command[1:-1])
elif command == "set":
    item, content = content.split(" ", 1)
        if item == "title":
            title = content[1:-1]
...
```

Note the use of a second argument to tell `split` how many times to do so; `'set title "foo"'.split(" ", 1) == ['set', 'title "foo"']`. Precisely how you implement will depend on the range of things you want to be able to parse.